# Pass parameter from Angularjs controller to $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

This is my Angularjs .config file that opens lead.html page whenever 'tasks' is activated from another html using ui-router.

```
    App
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){


            $stateProvider
            .state('tasks', {

                templateUrl: {{name}}.html,
                controller:"TasksController"
            });


        }]);
```

This is my Taskscontroller.js

```
    App
        .controller(
                "TasksController", [function($scope, $http,$window) {


            var self = this;
            self.name = 'lead'; // I wanna use this parameter in templateUrl
            console.log("In tasks Controller");

        }]);
```

I want to make the templateUrl take parameter from TasksController so that it redirects to relevant page based on the parameter set in TasksController.
Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: you can try something like below          
  '$stateProvider
            .state('tasks', {

                templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
     return $stateParams.name+ '.html';
   },
                controller:"TasksController"
            });'
But for this you'll have to know the name before hand

Answer (score 0):

You could try using $stateParams:

```
App.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateParams', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateParams) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tasks', {
      params: {
        page: null
      },
      templateUrl: {{$stateParams.page}}.html,
      controller: "TasksController"
    });
}]);
```

Then in your controller:

```
App.controller("TasksController", [function($scope, $http, $window, $stateParams, $state) {
  var self = this;
  self.$stateParams.page = 'some_url.html';
  self.$state.go('tasks');
}]);
```

Don't forget the injection in the controller too. Haven't tested this but you may need the $state go like this:

```
self.$state.go('tasks', { page: 'some_url.html' }, { });
```

Comment: But when am getting this error http://localhost:7001/gradDashboard/pages/%7B%7B$stateParams.page%7D%7D